# Given a pointer to a C++ object what are all the correct ways to call the operator[] function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am writing a time varying profile class using templates and want to index the profile by either a numeric index or by a date and time as represented by a struct tm.  The indexing by a numeric index works fine, but the indexing by a date doesn't work with a pointer to the object.  Here is some sample code containing approaches that work and approaches that don't work.

```
#include "profile.h" // Class Profile<T> is declared and defined here.
float f;
int i;
struct tm d;
Profile<float> p;
Profile<float> *pPtr;

// Non-pointer syntax
f = p[i];                // this works.
f = p.operator[](i);     // this works, but its ugly.
f = p[d];                // this works.
f = p.operator[](d);     // this works, but its ugly.

// Pointer syntax
f = (*pPtr)[i];          // this works.
f = pPtr->operator[](i); // this works, but its ugly.
f = (*pPtr)[d];          // this isn't what I typed.  I did f = *(pPtr)[d];
f = pPtr->operator[](d); // this works, but its ugly.
```

This C++ code is being written in Visual Studio 2008.  The compiler error message is error C2677 binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'tm' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

Given a pointer to a C++ object what are all the correct ways to call the operator[] function?

Comment: `f = (*pPtr)[d]; // this doesn't work.` I'd warrant that it _does_ work; what error are you seeing?

Comment: What do you mean `(*pPtr)[d]` doesn't work? As `*pPtr` yields a `Profile<float>&` this should accept a subscribe operator which is accepted for `p[d]`.

Comment: That is really weird!  After struggling for four hours and getting consistent compiler errors, now it starts working. 8^P

Comment: @JEdwardEllis : Perhaps you were trying `*pPtr[d]` or `*(pPtr)[d]` before.

Comment: Well at least I now have a very, very thorough test.

Comment: @ildjarn you are correct!  *(pPtr)[d] yields the error I've been seeing!  Please post that as an answer and I will accept it as the correct one!

Comment: Perhaps you added `Profile<float>::operator[](const ::tm&)` in the meantime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've shown here is fine; probably in your previous attempts you were doing `*(pPtr)[d]` instead of `(*pPtr)[d]`, which would understandably cause an error since `operator*` has lower precedence than `operator[]`.

Comment: Specifically I was doing *(pPtr)[d].

Answer (score 1):

You have listed the sensible options. I don't see why the pointer dereference wouldn't work. The following compiles just fine:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(0);
v[0];

std::vector<int>* vp = &v;
(*vp)[0];
```

Comment: Yes, mine now compiles too.  I have no explanation as to why I was getting compiler error C2677.

Answer (score 0):

In similar cases, i add additional method in class, such as 'at'.

```
templateType & Profile::at(int idx) 
{
    return operator[](idx);
}
```

So, code looks better :

```
f = pPtr->at(i);
```

By the way, using at(idx) in class methods (Profile in our case) would be easy that `operator[](idx)`.